# Como almacenar datos en un txt sin que se reemplace la entrada anteriror en C#

Tags: c#, txt

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual esta recibiendo datos a un arreglo para luego enviarlos a un archivo txt en C# pero el problema es que me reemplaza la entrada anterior y yo quiero que se almacene cada dato que va entrando al txt

```
//DatosdeCobos
datosCobos = new String[] {sqldate+" "+sqltime+" "+codigoLlanta+" "+modulo};
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter ("C:\\Users\\N033321a\\Desktop\\datosCobos.txt"))
{
    foreach (String datoscobos in datosCobos)
    {
        outputFile.WriteLine(datoscobos);
    }
}
```

Asi es como lo estoy haciendo pero solo me guarda una entrada
Ejemplo:

> 16-12-2019 11:33 T7NX 7

pero yo quiero que me guarde asi en el txt

> 16-12-2019 11:33 T7NX 7
>
> 16-12-2019 11:33 T7NX 8
>
> 16-12-2019 11:33 T7NX 9
>
> 16-12-2019 11:33 T7NX 10

Comment: outputFile tiene que estar abierta como append (que no me acuerdo si podes en un StreamWriter, en un fileWriter seguro podes)

Answer (score 3):

Debes indicar que abres el archivo para añadir con `append`:

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter ("C:\\Users\\N033321a\\Desktop\\datosCobos.txt", append: true))
```

Answer (score 1):

Si analizas el constructor de la clase

[StreamWriter(String, Boolean)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_)

veras que hay un segundo parametros

> **append**
>
> true para anexar datos al archivo; false para sobrescribir el archivo. Si el archivo especificado no existe, este parámetro no tiene ningún efecto y el constructor crea un nuevo archivo.

Pero existe la posibilidad de usar

[File.AppendText(String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8)

o

[File.AppendAllLines()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netframework-4.8)

con este podrias

```
var datosCobos = new String[] {sqldate+" "+sqltime+" "+codigoLlanta+" "+modulo};
string filePath = @"C:\Users\N033321a\Desktop\datosCobos.txt";

File.AppendAllLines(filePath, datosCobos);
```

asignar los datos en una sola linea sin iterar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es verificar si ya existe el directorio con la fecha actual e ir agregando el contenido que deseas.

```
string nombreFichero=DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() +
        DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() +
        DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + ".txt"
if (Directory.Exists(nombreArchivo))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(nombreArchivo);
            }
string textoAgregar= "";
        textoAgregar+= DateTime.Now + " - " + actividad + Environment.NewLine;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(nombreFichero, true);
        sw.Write(textoAgregar);
        sw.Close();
```